# Where to place secure headers in the application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http-headers

I was studying secure headers and came across some headers like `X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode = block`.
My doubt is where exactly to set these headers. I'm doing a reactjs + nodejs application. Would I set these headers in the `fetch()` that I do from the front to the back or would I set them in the `res.set()` of nodeJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection) for them say?

> The HTTP X-XSS-Protection **response header** is a feature of Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari that stops pages from loading when they detect reflected cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

It is a response header, so it goes on the response from the server.

Comment: in the case of nodejs then I would use res.set() or lib Helmet, right?

Comment: Those are among the options you have.